# Deprecation Warning when using nested elements pattern from Documentation

Tags: page-object-gem

Following the example on the wiki for finding nested elements (https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Nested-Elements), I was able to find items in a modal.

The problem is, i need to select them by index number, is there a way to do with this without using the deprecated functionality that passes the functionality to the underlying driver?

Current code is as follows.

```
  div(:add_line_modal, :id => 'add-line-modal')
  select(:add_line_service_select) do |page|
    page.add_line_modal_element.select(:index => 0)
  end
```

Throws this

```
*** DEPRECATION WARNING
*** You are calling a method named select at %PROJECTDIRECTORY%
*** This method does not exist in page-object so it is being passed to the driver.
*** This feature will be removed in the near future.
*** Please change your code to call the correct page-object method.
*** If you are using functionality that does not exist in page-object please request it be added.
```

Answer (score -1):

Look more careful at the [example](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Nested-Elements). The nested line is not just "unordered_list", it's "unordered_list_element".

When you want to describe an element outside an accessor you should add "_element":

```ruby
# accessor
link('ok', text: 'ok')

# outside accessor
def ok
  link_element(text: 'ok')
end
```

In your example you should use:

```ruby
page.add_line_modal_element.select_list_element(:index => 0)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I was attempting to use select_element when i tried this approach.